# json in python - can I do the same in Lua?

Tags: python, json, lua

```python
import json
def send_res(j): # EXAMPLE FUNCTION
    print(j)
send_res(json.dumps({'evt': 'n','m':'__string__'}))
```

My question is how can I do json like that in Lua? The server I'm building for is setup like that.

Would it be something like:

```lua
json = require('json');

function send_res(j) -- example function
    print(j);
end
local dict = {};
dict['evt'] = {};
dict['evt']['n'] = {};
dict['evt']['n']['m'] = '__string__';
send_res(json.encode(dict));
```

Comment: I feel stupid, now that I see my question I believe I know the answer

Comment: post the answer as an answer instead of adding it to the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. It's almost the same in lua, just drop a few parenthesis and replace `:` with `=` like so:

```
json = require 'json'

function send_res(j) -- example function
  print(j)
  end

send_res( json.encode{ evt = 'n', m = '__string__'} )
```

Answer (score -2):

if I'm not mistaken, it should be like this:

```
function send_res(j)
    print(j)
    local dict = {'evt'='n', 'm'='__string__'};
end
send_res(json.encode(dict));
```

Comment: `{evt='n', m='__string__'}` or `{['evt']='n', ['m']='__string__'}`, no semicolons necessary, and `dict` here is not in scope for the call.